# Enumeration of theorems with beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems, amsthm

How do I enumerate theorems in a beamer using `\newtheorem` with the amsthm package?

Comment: In future please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]` to your preamble:

[image]

Here is a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228):

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

  \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}
    This is the beginning of Theorem 1.
    \end{theorem}
    \end{frame}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I make the beamer number the definitions in the same way as the theorems?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Did you try? When the numbering of theorems is enabled all of the pre-defined theorem-like environments share a common counter. When asking questions please, at a minimum, test a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This will help you fine-tune your question and make it easier for people to understand what you are asking and make it easier for them to help you.